# Is it acceptable to use the fill attribute & style on an svg element?

Tags: html, svg

<strike>In the [svg2-draft specs](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#SVGElement) `fill` is not listed as one of the valid attributes of an `svg` element.</strike>

However `fill` is an inherited [HTML property](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#FillProperty) and [CSS property](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/fill.html), so it will be inherited by svg shapes.

**Is it acceptable to use the `fill` attribute &/or style on an `svg` element?**

**As opposed to using fill on the shapes (e.g. `<path>`) directly.**

*Stretch question:* Is it generally acceptable to use inheritable attributes/styles on any element regardless of whether it is a valid attribute/style (for that element) for the sole purpose of those attribute/styles being inherited to their intended child elements?

For example:

```
<svg fill="#a0a0a0">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

or

```
<svg class="SVG">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>

<style>
  .SVG { fill #a0a0a0; }
</style>
```

Comment: It may not list it directly in the docs but it is used throughout many of the examples, except they are not directly on the svg container but something within like a path or rec or <g>

Comment: My precise question is whether it is appropriate to use it directly on the svg container. Do you have some suggestions to clarify my question — so that this is unmistakeable?

Comment: I have updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: I advise you to use both.
inline style for fallback
and you can stylize it any way you want in css

Comment: The question is about whether using the fill attribute on an svg element compared to on each shape element is acceptable and correct. Your comment doesn't appear to grasp/relate to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the svg2-draft specs fill is not listed as one of the valid attributes of an svg element.

That's not correct.  `fill` is listed under [presentation attributes](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#TermPresentationAttribute).

So the answer to your question is: Yes. It is acceptable. :)

Comment: Ah! I was totally confused by the fact that clicking show resulted in only a dash - thinking that the subsequent attributes therefore were the only valid presentational attributes... when in fact the list wasn't showing due to being to large to load,  obvious in retrospect. Thank you.